# OutOfMemory Exception while running in Spark Scala shell

Tags: apache-spark

I was running some SQL commands connecting Spark with Hive in my cluster, but encountered this error half way. Any idea how to solve this?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Stopping spark context.
Exception in thread "main"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=256m**  in the spark.driver.extraJavaOptions like below:

```
 ./bin/spark-shell --master spark://servername:7077 --driver-class-path  
  $CLASSPATH --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=256m"
```